# Define multiple grids in Singularitygs v1.4

Tags: sass, singularitygs

I started upgrading a website from Singularity 1.1.2 to 1.4.0 and immediately hit a wall when it came to using multiple grids in the same style sheets. I have five different grids on this site. Previously I was able to set variables for each of the grids and gutters, like so...

```
$copy-grids: 2;
$copy-grids: add-grid(4 at $breakpoint-xs-min, $copy-grids);
$copy-grids: add-grid(6 at $breakpoint-l-min, $copy-grids);
$copy-gutters: $gutter-width;

$front-grids: 1;
$front-grids: add-grid(2 at $breakpoint-2up-min, $front-grids);
$front-grids: add-grid(3 at $breakpoint-3up-min, $front-grids);
$front-grids: add-grid(4 at $breakpoint-4up-min, $front-grids);
$front-gutters: breakpoint-to-base-em($front-gutter-width);

...
```

Then I was able to pass these variables to custom mixins using Singularity's `layout()` function, like this...

```
// Mixins for the main content body copy.
@mixin copy-layout {
  @include layout($copy-grids, $copy-gutters) {
    // All the things!
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin copy-grid-span($span, $location) {
  @include copy-layout {
    @include grid-span($span, $location);
  }
}

// Mixins for the front page.
@mixin front-layout {
  @include layout($front-grids, $front-gutters) {
    $gutter-styles: 'split' 'fixed';
    // All the things!
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin front-grid-span($span, $location) {
  @include front-layout {
    @include grid-span($span, $location);
  }
}

...
```

This let me use my custom mixins in place of the standard `grid-span()` mixins to easily implement any of my defined grids. For instance:

```
#block-bean-front-page-message {
  margin-bottom: $front-gutters;
  @include breakpoint-1up() {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 $front-gutters/2;
  }
  @include breakpoint-2up-to-4up() {
    @include front-grid-span(1, 2);
  }
  @include breakpoint-4up(true) {
    @include front-grid-span(3, 2);
  }
}
```

The problem is that, in Singularity v1.4, grid and gutter settings are no longer saved to normal sass variables. Instead they are saved as keyed values in the global `$Singularity-Settings` map. The keys used for these values are hard coded in the `add-grid()`, `add-gutter()`, and `add-gutter-style()` mixins, none of which accept a custom variable name. This appears to effectively prevent me from defining more than one grid. So while the `layout()` mixin still exists, I no longer have variables I can pass into it for my grid and gutter settings, breakng my custom layout wrapper mixins.

I've posted this as an [issue on Github](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/issues/197) and I understand a more permanent fix may be in the works. But in the mean time, I'm hoping there is a workaround I can use to accomplish multiple grids using the current release of Singularity.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I'm able to achieve what I'm after by overriding the add-grid(), add-gutter(), and add-gutter-style() mixins like so:

```
@mixin add-grid($grid-definition, $grid-key: 'grids') {
  $Grid-Map: ();
  @if sgs-has($grid-key) {
    $Grid-Map: sgs-get($grid-key);
  }
  @else {
    $New-Map: sgs-set($grid-key, $Grid-Map)
  }
  $Add-Grid: add-grid($grid-definition, $Grid-Map);
  $HOLDER: sgs-set($grid-key, $Add-Grid);
}

@mixin add-gutter($gutter-definition, $gutter-key: 'gutters') {
  $Gutter-Map: ();
  @if sgs-has($gutter-key) {
    $Gutter-Map: sgs-get($gutter-key);
  }
  @else {
    $New-Map: sgs-set($gutter-key, $Gutter-Map)
  }
  $Add-Gutter: add-gutter($gutter-definition, $Gutter-Map);
  $HOLDER: sgs-set($gutter-key, $Add-Gutter);
}

@mixin add-gutter-style($gutter-style-definition, $gutter-style-key: 'gutter styles') {
  $Gutter-Style-Map: ();
  @if sgs-has($gutter-style-key) {
    $Gutter-Style-Map: sgs-get($gutter-style-key);
  }
  @else {
    $New-Map: sgs-set($gutter-style-key, $Gutter-Style-Map)
  }
  $Add-Gutter-Style: add-gutter-style($gutter-style-definition, $Gutter-Style-Map);
  $HOLDER: sgs-set($gutter-style-key, $Add-Gutter-Style);
}
```

Then I can define my grids like this...

```
@include add-grid(2, 'copy grids');
@include add-grid(4 at $breakpoint-xs-min, 'copy grids');
@include add-grid(6 at $breakpoint-l-min, 'copy grids');
$copy-grids: sgs-get('copy grids');
@include add-gutter($gutter-width, 'copy gutters');
$copy-gutters: sgs-get('copy gutters');

@include add-grid(2, 'front grids');
@include add-grid(2 at $breakpoint-2up-min, 'front grids');
@include add-grid(3 at $breakpoint-3up-min, 'front grids');
@include add-grid(4 at $breakpoint-4up-min, 'front grids');
$front-grids: sgs-get('front grids');
@include add-gutter($front-gutter-width-em, 'front gutters');
$front-gutters: sgs-get('front gutters');
$front-gutter-styles: 'split' 'fixed';
```

...giving me variables which I can pass into the layout function. Right now everything seems to be working, except for the gutter styles, which don't seem to have any effect on output, but that's a different issue.